# Firebase Realtime database vs socket.io on AWS

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, websocket

I need suggestions.
I want to build Live location tracking app in android and iOS. So which should i choose for backend (Firebase Realtime database or Socket.io implementation on AWS).

My main concern is uses cost, means which is less costly?

Answer (score 3):

> which is less costly?

Costly can be time + money. I think using firebase will save you time over building a node server and implementing Socket.io.

When it comes to $$, you won't have to worry about that until the app really scales up. But sorry I don't know specifics about rates (I assume you'll get a better deal with IaaS solution rather than a [MBaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_backend_as_a_service), which is what Firebase is)

I created a location-based media sharing web app using Firebase, Google maps, and  [geofire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire). As a beginner web developer, it was pretty easy to get up and running!

Granted, I don't know a lot about AWS, but it seems the learning curve is a lot steeper.